# "I'm also a little bit a system administrator and an IT support engineer" - is this article usage okay?

Tags: articles

I'm trying to write some description about myself, but have doubts about articles. Here's the sentence:

> I'm passionate about software development, also I'm a computer geek, a little bit system administrator and IT support engineer.

But if I use articles the sentence sounds more awkward:

> I'm passionate about software development, also I'm a computer geek, a little bit **a** system administrator and **an** IT support engineer.

Please suggest what the right variant is. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It requires 'of' there...after 'bit'. But I'd say... I'm **more** an IT support engineer than a system admin if the choice is between those two. :)

Comment: I do not agree that this is sheer proofreading. The OP have provided a "source of confusion". Mind if one of the closers lighten me up a bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One stock expression is "*a little bit of a [noun phrase]*". Hence,

> I'm passionate about software development; I'm also a computer geek, a little bit **of a** system administrator and **an** IT support engineer.

Answer (score 1):

The usage is definitely better with the a and an.

I still have questions, though. Are you trying to say that you are 4 things:

- software developer
- computer geek
- (a little bit a) system administrator
- IT support engineer.

Or, are you a software developer, with an additional interest in hardware (i.e. a computer geek), using experience in system administration and support engineering as examples?

If you are writing this for a resume or profile, I would avoid using the term computer geek, as this could be taken as insulting, overly informal, or non-specific depending on your audience.

As a further aside, stating that you are passionate about something is not very effective. It is better to state how you demonstrate your passion for a topic, for example: I share my passion for software development through my involvement in such-and-such user group, etc.